# Bootstrap Unity IoC container in Windows Service and Reference in dependent library

Tags: c#, windows-services, unity-container, ioc-container

I currently have a windows service and I want to use Unity for IoC and dependency injection.  I want the objects/classes/dependent projects within my application to be able to access the IoC container in the service.  How should I wire up the IoC container so my embedded classes/objects can reference them?

To add more detail: My service starts a worker process that processes a queue (QueueProcessor).  The queue processor in turn utilizes a set of providers that conform to an interface, for the purposes of discussion we'll call it IProvider.  Each provider implementing the IProvider interface in turn requires a data store that also conforms to an interface, call it IDataStore.  The hierarchy continues further but the point here is the service is one project, the providers are in another project, and the data store is in yet another project.  I want to be able to use the IoC container at the various levels in my application.  I'm looking for the best way to bootstrap the IoC container to make that happen.

Comment: Are the classes/projects all part of the windows service solution? Not sure what's different from a standard Unity setup here.

Comment: The short answer is that you should _not_ leet any application code depend upon the Container, since that leads to the [Service Locator anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/). The long answer is that if you want a long answer, you should add much more details to your question, with realistic code examples explaining why you think that your application code needs to call back into the container.